# I didn't receive the bounty for a question I answered

Tags: support, specific-question, bounty

I answered a question which had a bounty of 50 points. The bounty is now over and the only answer on that question is my own, however I didn't receive the bounty? There was definitely a bounty on the question when I answered it, here is a link: [iAd interstitial not working on device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31573864/iad-interstitial-not-working-on-device/31672303#31672303)

Comment: It's odd that the question does not have the blue bounty notification next to it.

Comment: Yeah, its really weird. You can even see in the comments under my answer that he will accept my answer for the bounty

Comment: I found the question in the featured tab, with a +50 badge. The bounty was definitely active when I answered the question, i'm 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 11):

Your answer had only 1 upvote when the bounty period ended, so it was not auto-awarded to you.

[Bounty on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/31573864/revisions) was started on Jul 25 at 4:21 and it ended on Aug 2 at 5:24. While you received 1 upvote on Jul 31st and then the second upvote on Aug 3rd.

> [How is bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period),
>   the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a
>   minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount.

Comment: Link to the timeline for correlation: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31573864/timeline

Comment: I also didn't get the bounty for a question which I answered after a lot of analysis, even the user who had posted the question has accepted it within the bounty period. Still, I didn't get bounty... It doesn't feel good.

Here is the question which had no answer since 6 years: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32124110/grouping-consecutive-documents-with-elasticsearch/69305605#69305605

Comment: The person who had started the bounty has to award it manually. System will auto-award only if the answer has 2 or more score. Please read the "How is a bounty awarded?" section of [bounty help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). It states: "click the bounty award icon next to each answer to permanently award your bounty to the answerer"